# Interrupt and stop div scrolling on click using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

In my web app I have the inertia scrolling on divs enabled for webkit browsers. The problem is that when I click a button that executes a jquery function, if the div is still currently scrolling the function wont run until after it has come to a complete stop. Is there a way to interrupt and stop the div scroll in it's current position, the same way it works when a div is scrolling and then the user touches the screen? I'm assuming there is, but cant find exact code examples on how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, it could be difficult to offer a solution. Have you tried using `.stop()`?

Comment: didn't post any code because theres nothing special about it - standard div, standard scroll function. Just need a jquery click way of stopping the scroll in it's tracks. BTW, just tried .stop(); but it didn't work.

Comment: btw the div scrolling is a standard native swipe scroll, no jquery event or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The browser seemed to ignore click functions until the div would stop scrolling, so if you use 'jQuery tap' or jquery mobile (or any other plugin that enabled the tap function) and use '.tap' instead of '.click' it works fine. It won't stop the div from scrolling, but it will run the function anyway.